# Can reports created using CR 9.0 can be used with newer versions of Crystal reports?

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports

The users are having some report files (rpt) created using Crystal reports 9.0. But I find that support for crystal report 9.0 is discontinued. So can reports created using CR 9.0 can be used with newer versions of Crystal reports which are available?

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

of course ! From crystal report version 9.0 all report can be open in the newer crystal report.
With older report than 9.0 you have to open and re-save the report from a version of the Crystal Reports designer application at least as recent as version 9